# What does --only=dev mean in package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install

`"cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"`

- What does `--only=dev` mean in package.json.
- How does its absence affect the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This controls whether development or production dependencies (and not both) are installed, as seen [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

```
The --only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]} argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the NODE_ENV.
```